# Can't understand the syntax of Promise.resolve which is used instead of try-catch block

Tags: node.js, express, promise, try-catch

I can not understand how this thing works. can anyone explain please

`

```
module.exports = (thefunc) => (req,res,next)=>{
    Promise.resolve(thefunc(req,res,next)).catch(next)
}
```

`

i searched on internet and still can not understand.

Answer (score 2):

The point of this structure:

```
Promise.resolve(thefunc(req,res,next)).catch(next)
```

Is to catch any rejected promise that might be returned from calling:

```
thefunc(req,res,next)
```

And, direct the reject reason to call `next(err)`.  It is wrapped in `Promise.resolve()` in case `thefunc(req,res,next)` does not return a promise at all (perhapes even returns nothing).  This makes it type-safe to add the `.catch()`.

This attempts to add a bit of promise-awareness to your routing engine since Express, by itself, does not have promise-awareness for route handlers.

So, this will work with any of these situations inside of `thefunc()`:

```
async function(req, res, next)  {
    if (!req.body.username) throw new Error("User Missing");
    ....
}
```

In this case, the function use here is declared as `async` so when it uses `throw`, that will cause it reject the promise that it returns.  That will then end up call `next(err)` where `err` is the Error object we created there.

```
function(req, res, next)  {
    return queryMyDb(...).then(result => {
        res.send(result);
    });
}
```

In this case, if the DB query rejects, then this function will be returning a promise that rejects and the reject reason will be sent to `next(err)` just like in the previous example by the wrapper.

```
function(req, res, next) {
    res.send({cntr: req.body.cntr++});
}
```

While this request handler doesn't cause any sort of error (assuming `req.body.cntr` is valid), it also doesn't return a promise.  But, because the function call was wrapped in `Promise.resolve(theFunc(...))` that still allows the wrapper to use the `.catch()` which won't actually come into play because no error occurs here, but adding the `.catch()` won't cause a run-time error because of the `Promise.resolve()` wrapper.

---

Note, the wrapper as shown will not catch synchronous exceptions thrown in the route handler unless the route handler is declared `async` (which auto-converts synchronous exceptions to a rejected promise for you).

If you want to also catch synchronous exceptions (generally advisable), you can modify it to this:

```
module.exports = (thefunc) => (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        Promise.resolve(thefunc(req,res,next)).catch(next)
    } catch(e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

Though, at that point, I would probably do this:

```
module.exports = async (thefunc) => (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
        await thefunc(req,res,next);
    } catch(e) {
        next(e);
    }
}
```

Since it is harmless to use `await` on a non-promise, you don't have to wrap with `Promise.resolve()` when using `await` like this.  If `thefunc()` happens to return a promise that rejects or happens to throw synchronously, the `try/catch` will catch either.

Comment: @CherryDT - Excellent point.  I've added description of that and even modifications of the wrapper that will catch synchronous exceptions.

Comment: Interesting, it's slightly unintuitive since it's different from other cases - throwing in the Promise constructor will result in only a rejection, as will throwing in an `async` function, but here with `Promise.resolve`, it'll stop execution completely

Comment: @CertainPerformance - Yep, because throwing syncnronously there happens BEFORE `Promise.resolve()` is called as it's preparing arguments for the call to `Promise.resolve()`.